# Spring and H2 migrations

Tags: java, spring, migration, h2

I wanted to migrate my H2 db from my previous app(no Spring) to new app(with Spring).
I was told that all I need to do is copy/paste, my migrations, so I did, unfortunately when I tried to run the app, I got this ↓
[image]
It says there are some sorts of syntax errors, but I had no error starting this db with previous app:

Syntax error in SQL statement "CREATE TABLE LANGUAGES (
    ID INT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    WELCOMEMSG VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    CODE VARCHAR(3),
)[*]"; expected "identifier"; SQL statement:
create table languages (
    id int unsigned primary key auto_increment,
    welcomeMsg varchar(100) not null,
    code varchar(3),
) [42001-200]
Location   : db/migration/V1__Create_languages_table.sql (C:\Users\ja\Downloads\hello 
(1)\hello\target\classes\db\migration\V1__Create_languages_table.sql)
Line       : 1
Statement  : create table languages (
    id int unsigned primary key auto_increment,
    welcomeMsg varchar(100) not null,
    code varchar(3),
)

Just to make sure, there is the troubled code

```
create table languages (
id int unsigned primary key auto_increment,
welcomeMsg varchar(100) not null,
code varchar(3),
```

);

I'm only a learner in Java/programming, it's all a bit new for me. Any help much appreciate

Comment: Get rid of the last comma. It sould end  code varchar(3))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove invalid comma before closing parenthesis; it is not silently ignored by H2 any more, only old versions of H2 can parse it. 1.4.200 is more strict.

I also suggest you to remove the `UNSIGNED` modifier, it will not be allowed by 1.4.201 in regular mode. It will be accepted only in MySQL compatibility mode (and ignored, just like in 1.4.200).

Comment: Thank you @EvgenijRyazanov that did help! Unfortunately I can't upvote your answer. Nonetheless thanks again!

Comment: You are a life saver! I literally spent 5 hours adjusting all my h2 schema code after upgrading from 2.2.0 of Spring Boot to 2.2.5 thinking I have invalid queries. In the end it was just one simple darn comma! Thank you!